# Is there a way for docker-compose to save and open a docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerpy

With the native docker client daemon, you can save images to a file and then load them.

As an example, from [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/):

```
$ docker save busybox > busybox.tar
$ ls -sh busybox.tar
2.7M busybox.tar
$ docker save --output busybox.tar busybox
$ ls -sh busybox.tar
2.7M busybox.tar
$ docker save -o fedora-all.tar fedora
$ docker save -o fedora-latest.tar fedora:latest
```

I would like to do the same functionality using docker-compose. However, [it doesn't appear to support save/load](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/) in their documentation.

The reason I would like to do this is I am running docker-compose in an environment where it communicates via the docker sock, but does not have docker itself installed. I cannot install a docker client in this environment (but docker-compose is installed). **Docker is not installed and does not have to be installed for docker-compose to work.** ALL docker-compose requires is a connection to /var/run/docker.sock and it uses [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/requirements.txt#L4) to talk over this.

I guess I could write a simple script using `docker-py` to do this but I am hoping to do this through docker-compose itself.

Is there a way for `docker-compose` to load an image file saved with `docker save` or to do the equivalent command?

Comment: @SimonBoudrias that's not how docker-compose works. It communicates directly on the docker sock and does not require docker itself to be installed. Docker must be installed _somewhere_ but does not necessarily have to be installed where docker-compose is.

Comment: it just a schedule tool which consume the docker API I think, so for save, it still need use docker actually.

Comment: Answers go in the answers, folks.

Comment: @LipingHuang using docker-compose does not require docker installed in the environment you are using it. All it requires is a the ability to connect to the docker-api to a location a valid docker instance is working. This does not have to be in the same environment `docker-compose` is running in.

Comment: Just a note on how docker API can be used to save an image: `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/images/get?names=fedora >fedora.tar` ([requires](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/#/using-docker-machine-with-the-api) curl >7.40)

Answer (score -2):

> Is there a way for docker-compose to load an image file saved with docker save or to do the equivalent command?

There is not. Your best option is to write a script with `docker-py`